# How to create a boostrap nav-bar and reuse it on every page

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I need to reuse the `boostrap` `navbar` on all pages so I been trying to have a single file for the menu and render it using a `ng-include` `angularJS` tag

The menu is this file `/partials/top_menu.html`

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">EXAMPLE</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                <a href="about.html">Quienes Somos</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="organizacion.html">Organizaci&oacute;n</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="servicios.html">Servicios</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="clientes.html">Clientes</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="portfolio-3-col.html">Galeria</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div>
```

And here is the index.html that tries to include that partial as the navigation menu of the page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>TITLE</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/modern-business.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top topnav" role="navigation">
        <div ng-include="'partials/top_menu.html'"></div>
    </nav>
<body>
```

**The problem is that the menu bar is not being render at all and the WebDeveloper console does not show any error or file missing**

What am I doing wrong or if this is the wrong aproach to do it let me know can I achieve it

Comment: you can put the <nav> tag inside the partial too and just use <div ng-include

Comment: also you can make a custom directive to achieve it, but its better to use ng include

Comment: @Tomislav as you probably saw my index.html points to other html files that need to include that menu as well.

Comment: Well I thought that you want to develop SPA (single page app) using partials and routing. If not then your approach is ok.

Comment: @Tomislav but the menu is not being rendered

Comment: @Mayur already tried that but navbar is not being rendered

Comment: @Tomislav and Mayur I have updated my last part of the question to clarify what the problem is

Comment: Also you are missing ng-app directive in your index.html. Try with <body ng-app>

Comment: @Tomislav please post that and the $scope as an answer since is now working

Comment: I am glad to help. Please mark it as correct answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85245/discussion-between-mauricio-gracia-and-tomislav).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `ng-app` to the body tag of your index.html

```
<body ng-app>
```

This is AngularJS bootstraping directive. Without this, the AngularJS process does not start.

And you need to do that for any html file that needs to use `angularJS` directives

Comment: That means that you are not using SPA approach. In about.html you have to include all the header scripts as in index.html, include all css files and also set <body ng-app>.

Comment: You really heva to consider using routing and partial views. That's the core of the AngularJS

Answer (score -1):

Use this script may be it help you :

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#includedContent").load("b.html"); 
    });
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
     <div id="includedContent"></div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Must include Jquery file.